# How to rename a folder and some of its content from a text returned variable

Tags: applescript, file-rename

What i want is to do a find and replace command with applescript. I know I can use namechanger and other programs but that takes too many steps. I'm all about efficiency.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selected_items to selection
    set jobNum to text returned of (display dialog "Job Number:" default answer "")
    set name of document folder selection to jobNum (*if it did work it would rename the entire folder which isn't what I want.  My goal is to replace all "12345" with the value of jobNum*)
end tell
```

sample folder structure (i can't submit images yet because I need 10pts)

```
main folder: 12345_Sample Job Folder
 - 12345_D.ai
 - 12345_P.ai
 - Proofs
 - Working Files
      - 12345.ai
```

Comment: In your example, are you trying to change every occurrence of **12345** to your input string?  The Job Folder, and all 3 .ai files as well?  Going to something like **52161_Sample Job Folder**, 52161_D.ai, etc.?

Comment: … and has the find pattern always 5 characters or a variable length with a underscore as separator?

Comment: Yes, every instance of 12345 should be replaced by the input string. There is always an underscore after the 1st 5 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
set jobFolder to choose folder with prompt "Choose the Job Folder:"

tell application "Finder"
    set rootName to jobFolder's name
    set searchString to my FindSearchString(rootName)
    set replaceString to text returned of (display dialog ("This script will search for files that contain " & searchString & ".  Please enter the replacement text and click OK.") default answer searchString)
    set everything to every file in (jobFolder's entire contents)
    repeat with onething in everything
        if ((onething's name) as text) contains searchString then
            set onething's name to my replace_chars(((onething's name) as text), searchString, replaceString)
        end if
    end repeat
    set jobFolder's name to my replace_chars(((jobFolder's name) as text), searchString, replaceString)
end tell
---------------------------------
on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
    return this_text
end replace_chars
---------------------------------
to FindSearchString(txt)
    set astid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "_"
    set sst to txt's text item 1
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
    return sst
end FindSearchString
```

This will only affect filenames within the initial chosen folder, not subfolder names.  At the very end, it changes the name of the chosen folder.

The renaming handler is based on the code at the bottom of [this page](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-06.html)

Comment: It worked only to the base folder but it's a start. I will have to tweak this code to work at the end of another script. What I'm doing is taking a selected job from our server and then duplicating that file to my desktop. It will delete certain folder and files that are not usable and finally renames the job folder and certain files to my input. Again, thank you for your help! I truly appreciate the time and effort you put into helping me out. Have a great day:-)